# asp.net mvc [Authorize()]

Tags: asp.net, authorization, roles

I have a controller and I want two roles to be able to access it. 1-admin OR (2-moderator and editor)

Right now I have something like but don't know where to put the the OR operation.

```
[Authorize(Roles=Admin)]
 public ActionResult myAction()
 {
 }
```